# Setting default size/text of custom control in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I am creating a custom control in my C# application in order to add a new property (MyProperty below). It is inheriting from Label. One thing I would like it to do, is display at a particular size when I drag it on to my form (200x132). I'd also like it to display no text. However, no matter how I try to do this, it doesn't seem to work. I am able to set BackColor and BorderStyle with no problem, however. I'm fairly new to C#, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyProgram
{

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Value1, Value2, Value3
    }

    public partial class MyControl : Label
    {

        public MyControl()
        {
            BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            AutoSize = false;
            Size = new Size(200, 132);
            Text = "";
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }

        private MyEnum myProperty;

        public MyEnum MyProperty
        {
            get { return myProperty; }
            set { myPropery = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you musto set properties of control after calling  InitializeComponent(); method

Comment: @mohsen I had tried this before, but it didn't seem to make a difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer provided via Dispersia's link has a bug, in my opinion. The text reset should happen once and then whatever a user does after that shouldn't matter. In Dispersia's link you can't actually set the text back to the control name because it will keep blanking it out.

The answer provided by cramopy doesn't technically answer your question, it is a way to do it by using the defaults on a `UserControl` though. You'll also need to bind the `Text` property of the `UserControl` to the label's.

The following should work while inheriting from a `Label` and will only reset the `Text` property once.

```
public partial class MyControl : Label
{

    #region fields

    private IComponentChangeService _changeService;
    private bool canResetText = false;

    #endregion

    #region properties

    protected override Size DefaultSize
    {
        get { return new Size(200, 132); }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public override bool AutoSize
    {
        get { return false; }
        set { base.AutoSize = false; }
    }

    public override ISite Site
    {
        get { return base.Site; }
        set
        {
            base.Site = value;

            if (!base.DesignMode)
                return;

            this._changeService = (IComponentChangeService)base.GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));

            if (this._changeService != null)
                this._changeService.ComponentChanged += new ComponentChangedEventHandler(this.OnComponentChanged);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region constructors

    public MyControl()
    {
        base.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
        base.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }

    #endregion

    #region methods

    protected override void InitLayout()
    {
        base.InitLayout();

        this.canResetText = true;
    }

    private void OnComponentChanged(object sender, ComponentChangedEventArgs ce)
    {
        if (ce.Component != null &&
            ce.Component == this &&
            ce.Member.Name == "Text" &&
            base.DesignMode &&
            this.canResetText)
        {
            ((MyControl)ce.Component).Text = string.Empty;

            this.canResetText = false;

            if (this._changeService != null)
                this._changeService.ComponentChanged -= new ComponentChangedEventHandler(this.OnComponentChanged);
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. It's a bit beyond my current knowledge level, but it will be a good learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

**@Dispersia** reply only answers the `myControl1` thing. **(deleted meanwhile)**

Here comes a **full** guide for solving your problem:

- Add a new `UserControl` named `MyLabel`
- Change the following within Designer Mode:

  - `BorderStyle`:= `FixedSingle`
  - `Size`:= `200; 132`
- Now Drag&Drop a new `Label` onto the control
- Edit those `Label` values (also within Designer Mode):

  - `AutoSize`:= `false`
  - `BackColor`:= `LightCoral`
  - `Dock`:= `Fill`
  - `Text`:= `clear/empty this box!!` (don't write this inside the box, you really have to clear it!)
  - `TextAlign`:= `MiddleCenter`

Just recompile your project && add a `MyLabel` control from the Toolbar.
Now it show up as you wanted!!

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get this to partially work (maybe I didn't do it quite right?). I still had an issue with AutoSize being set to true (and therefore the 200x132 size didn't "kick in" until I manually set it to false) and the text wouldn't disappear.